# How to pass HTML markup in UI bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI bootstrap to create modal dialog. It works fine if I use "templateUrl" and use "ng-template" to include the html template. But as I have multiple modal dialogs, my page is getting bigger and bigger after including all the html templates in the page using "ng-template".

Here's the code:
HTML

```
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@1.3.2" data-semver="1.3.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body content goes here...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Show modal</button>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('mydemo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('mydemo').controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size
    });
  };
});

angular.module('mydemo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Is there any way I can use HTML markup directly instead of using "templateUrl"?
Or atleast a way through which I can keep the html templates in a separate file instead of including it in the page using ng-template?
Here's the working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HqThAG79r22K2VGZSs2D?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you have a few options for indicating which content the modal will load.

1. As @Wes answered and demonstrated in his plunker fork, you can create an external html file somewhere in your application, and as long as you specify the correct path to the file, the modal will work as expected.
2. As you already have working the the plunker you linked to, you can put the template inside a script `type="text/ng-template"` tag and reference the value of its `id` attribute in your modal config.
3. A final way is to inline the html in the modal config. [Here's your plunker forked with the html directly added to the `template` property of the modal config as a string.](http://plnkr.co/edit/qhQBugnHCBwdhl7UgYDF?p=preview)

   ```
   var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
     template: '<div class="modal-header">' +
                 '<h3 class="modal-title">I\'m a modal!</h3>' +
               '</div>' +
               '<div class="modal-body">' +
                 'Modal body content goes here...' +
               '</div>' +
               '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                 '<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>' +
               '</div>',
     controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
     size: size
   });
   ```

This method works just fine, but it can be a little cumbersome to write, read, and maintain, depending on the amount of markup in the template.

Comment: @BennettAdams Could you expain more specific of second way?

Comment: @CanetRobern, sure. You can put your template in a script tag in another template (a parent or abstract template that will have already been loaded by the time you are calling the modal). The script would need an `id` and `type` attributes, e.g. `id="my-modal-template"` and `type="text/ng-template"`. And in the `modalInstance` config you would use the `templateUrl` property rather than `template`, and the value would be the `id` of the template in the script.

Comment: @BennettAdams Oh I got it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: how if we load html content from db and passing it to the modal-body?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use regular html.  Updated your plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/v0BYhg3ojCgy7eiebRvR?p=preview

This just requires you know the path to the HTML file.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mydemo">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@1.3.2" data-semver="1.3.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Show modal</button>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and your new myContent.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Modal body content goes here...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Wes. But is there any option in UI Bootstrap where I can pass HTML markup in modal instead of passing external html template?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution using [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

A forked plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ukqmThpvi4aRGLZEiSSe?p=preview

**JS - templates.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mydemo');

app.run(function($templateCache){

  $templateCache.put('tplcache/myContent.htm',
    '<div class="modal-header">' +
      '<h3 class="modal-title">I\'m a modal!</h3>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="modal-body">' +
        'Modal body content goes here...' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="modal-footer">' +
        '<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>' +
      '</div>');

})
```

**JS - modal config**

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'tplcache/myContent.htm',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size
});
```

**HTML Scripts (include templates.js after main app)**

```
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="templates.js"></script>
```

**HTML body**

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Show modal</button>
  </div>
</body>
```