# How to pass html markup to ui bootstrap modal?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have many modal sources in separated `html`s.

And I don't wanna make each html of modals.

In this case how can I pass my html code of modal into ui-bootstrap?

[How to pass HTML markup in UI bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603057/how-to-pass-html-markup-in-ui-bootstrap-modal/37604937)

Above link is exactly same as what I want to do.

And there are answer of @BennettAdams, it could help me almost,

but he did not explain of his second way.

I want some example of second way.

> As you already have working the the plunker you linked to, you can put
>   the template inside a script type="text/ng-template" tag and reference
>   the value of its id attribute in your modal config.

Thanks in advance, please help me. :)

Comment: you can also use `bind-html` directive

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović thanks for your advice. Could you give me some code or more specific information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to use the id of [script tag](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) as `templateUrl` of modal. 
From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script):

> Load the content of a `<script>` element into `$templateCache`, so that
>   the template can be used by `ngInclude`, `ngView`, or directives. The type
>   of the `<script>` element must be specified as `text/ng-template`, and a
>   cache name for the template must be assigned through the element's `id`,
>   which can then be used as a directive's `templateUrl`.

Working example:

```js
angular.module('mydemo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('mydemo').controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modalTemplate.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size
    });
  };
});

angular.module('mydemo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mydemo">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@1.3.2" data-semver="1.3.2" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Show modal</button>
  </div>

</body>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalTemplate.html"><h1>Helo from ng-template!</h1></script>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Your plunker is very nice and easy to understand! Thank you so much. :)